# Flex Slider - animation not working

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider, transition

Since upgrading from the Flexslider 1 to Flexslider 2 my animations aren't working (fade or otherwise).
I'm getting no js errors, I've checked my doc type and the css all seems correct. It just doesn't seem to transition. Also when I navigate from one slide to the next via the navigation spots it stops auto-playing forever.
Here is the js code I'm using:

```
$('.flexslider-desk').flexslider({
      animation: "fade",
      controlNav: true,  
      slideshow: true,
      slideshowSpeed:  7000,
      animationSpeed:  2000 ,
      directionNav:false,
      controlsContainer: $(".custom-controls-container")
  });
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! For anybody interested, Flexslider 2 screwed up the css transition for fade for webkit based browsers. Thankfully they provide the option to use jquery easing instead. Just include jquery.easing.js, and use the following parameters to your flexslider:

```
   easing: 'linear',
   animation: "fade", 
   slideshowSpeed: 5000,
   animationSpeed: 500,
   animationLoop: true, 
   smoothHeight: false,  
   useCSS: false,
```